# echo mysql value into table using Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Im, using PHP,AJAX,html to display mysql data into a table, I have managed to pass the data across using ajax as i can display it in the dev console but i can't get it to output to the table, I think im either missing a bit or have written in the table part incorrectly but it doesn't return errors it just returns item.beacon.

EDIT: after a recommendation to use APPEND I have updated the code to the below but it returns neither a error or any data even though data is still present.

if there is any more information needed i will update the question to include it.

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
#   header('Content-Type: applicaton/json');

$sql = "SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT
  beacon,location,date,
  COUNT(location) AS counter 
FROM `track`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() and `time` > NOW() - interval 60 second
GROUP BY beacon) AS SubQueryTable
ORDER BY SubQueryTable.counter DESC;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
   $rows = array();
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
   }

   echo json_encode($rows);
$conn->close();
?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
 <title>PHP MySQL</title>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
 </head>

 <body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch.php",
    data: "getrow",
}).done(function( data ) {
    $('table').append('<tr><td>'+data['beacon']+'</td></tr><tr> <td>'+data['location']+'</td></tr>'); 
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert('Request Failed');
});
}); 
</script>


<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var sec = 0;

function pad(val) {
return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
var timer = setInterval(function () {
$(".seconds").html(pad(++sec % 60));
$(".minutes").html(pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)));
}, 1000);
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont see any code that would even attempt to place the returned data into the table ??? Please show us what you have written to add these rows to the table.

Comment: i was using item.beacon to return the value to table but as said im not sure whether i im missing the echo etc, the values display as item.beacon,item.location in the dev console so i thought i may be able to call them into the table row that way

Comment: You need to insert the rows into your table "manually" in the forEach loop. For instance with a jQuery append. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @Michael I have had a look through some documents online but not sure where i would make the changes is it possible you could provide a example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below. I just commented the id because I do not see Id in your sql queries. Please ensure to include your jquery files.

If you try either get and post method

```
  type: 'get',
   type: 'post',
```

**Run the code below and it will work**

```
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch.php',
        type: 'get',
//type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                //var id = response[i].id;
                var beacon = response[i].beacon;
                var location = response[i].location;


                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + location + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
            }

        }
    });
});

</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="userTable" border="1" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">S.no</th>
                        <th width="20%">Beacon</th>
                        <th width="20%">Location</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will also appreciate if you can upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks bro success in your endeavour